# Az copy remove files is failing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azcopy

The azcopy to remove files failed when I tried to remove a folder with subfolders and files from a **fileshare** with **azcopy v10**.

My az copy command was as follows

`azcopy rm https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/SystemScheduledJobs-22-06-01?<sas-token>   --recursive=true`

The error which I was getting is

`panic: inconsistent path separators. Some are forward, some are back. This is not supported.`

and the stack trace

```
goroutine 565 [running]:
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/common.DeterminePathSeparator({0xc0071c6d00, 0x3e})
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/common/extensions.go:140 +0x97
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/common.GenerateFullPath({0x0, 0x0}, {0xc0071c6d00, 0x3e})
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/common/extensions.go:155 +0xe5
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/common.GenerateFullPathWithQuery({0x0, 0x248f909e0be}, {0xc0071c6d00, 0xb85c3d}, {0x0, 0x0})
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/common/extensions.go:172 +0x34
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*JobPartPlanHeader).TransferSrcDstStrings(0x248f8ec0000, 0x1853)
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/ste/JobPartPlan.go:181 +0x28f
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobPartMgr).ScheduleTransfers(0xc000029500, {0x17c3190, 0xc0005b2000})
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/ste/mgr-JobPartMgr.go:418 +0x692
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobMgr).scheduleJobParts(0xc0007a3880)
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/ste/mgr-JobMgr.go:851 +0x3e
created by github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.NewJobMgr
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/ste/mgr-JobMgr.go:180 +0x9a6
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could provide more insight into this issue.

Comment: From the error messages, it seems the delimiter (path separator) used in blob names have both forward and backward slashes. Can you check that? Ideally it should be `/`.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri , I did check on it but I could not find any character related to '/' or '\' in the blob names. also I am using the delete folder contents in first of file share folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment using the powershell command I got result successfully.***

***Powershell command***

```
azcopy rm https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/<path>?<sas-token> --recursive=true
```

**Output:**

[image]

***FileShare Url** `(https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/<path>)`

[image]

SAS Token at Storage Account level..
[image]

kindly check once with path in your url and try to reproduce once again.

***Reference:***

[azcopy remove | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove)

Comment: Hi VenkatesanSettu-MT , I tried again it seems the path and the SAS is correct because when I try with another folder it is working perfectly fine. But thank you so much for all the effort in explaining the steps .

Comment: @Venkatesan.S-MT - don't ask people to "click the check mark."